# Computational error in PGFPlots output?

Tags: pgfplots

I was trying to plot a function with `pgfplots`, but somehow `\addplot` is not producing the right graph. In the MWE below, I used both `\addplot` (blue line) and `\draw` (orange line) to generate the graph of the same function. But as you can see, the outputs are different. I believe the one produced by `\draw` is the correct version.

**Is this a bug with `pgfplots` or am I doing something wrong with it?**

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,scale=5]
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lambda{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\y{9}
  \begin{axis}[domain=0:1,ymin=0,ymax=1,samples=500]
    \addplot[blue](\x,{exp(\lambda*(1-\x))/(exp(\lambda*\y*\x)+exp(\lambda*(1-\x)))});
    \draw[orange,samples=500,domain=0:1]plot(axis cs:\x,{exp(\lambda*(1-\x))/(exp(\lambda*\y*\x)+exp(\lambda*(1-\x)))});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace macro `\y` by some other macro name.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: Thanks! That's the problem!

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: Would you perhaps post a short answer explaining the significance of `\y` in `pgfplots`?

Comment: I have no clue on significance of `\y` in pgfplots. It was just a guess.

Comment: Just as `\x` can be used for the `x` variable, `\y` can be used for the `y` variable. (Although it's more common to use just `x` and `y`, the backslashes are not needed.)  I haven't been able to trace what happens in the code, but `pgfplots` does at some point `/pgfplots/variable y/.initial=\y,`, and it seems at some other point that that gets a value of zero, which is the value used in your `\addplot` (try changing `9` to `0`, and see that the `\draw` plot becomes the same).